# Importing a file from a Python package in to a directory

Tags: python

I'm building a Python package and came across this situation. Here's the project structure :

```
my-package/
      examples/
           example.py
      my-package/
           __init__.py
           basic.py
           main.py
```

From the above project structure we can see that `my-package` is a package while `examples` is just a directory. Here what would be the best way to import `basic.py` in `example.py`.

`from my-package import basic` in `example.py` would throw `No module named ...`.

Comment: Why can't you make examples directory as a Python package?

Comment: @GregEremeev I can do that and make things work but I'm interested in knowing the other way.

Comment: But do you understand that the first way is better? Tweaking with sys.path is less practical. Relative imports inside packages are easy and readable.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you can do is add a `__init__.py` file under `my-package` so that the `my-package` will become a package directory so that the modules inside it can be imported to the file

Comment: ...and make `examples` a package too. That would solve all import problems given that your client code imports the outer package for run and use, and you don't try to start some script inside the package code.

Answer (score 0):

can you try creating an `__init__.py` under the main directory, and let me know about the results?

`__init__.py`:

```
import my-package.basic as basic
```

`example.py`:

```
from .. import basic
```

the final directory structure should be like:

```
my-package/
      __init__.py
      examples/
           example.py
      my-package/
           __init__.py
           basic.py
           main.py
```